# mysql select not woking for varchar field

Tags: mysql, select, varchar

I have table with email field of type varchar.

```
select * 
from `table_name` 
WHERE email='some email'
```

working well for all the other email except one email in the table.

Comment: can you give me email?

Answer (score 9):

When this works for your problematic record

```
select * from table_name 
where email like '%some email%'
```

Then you have leading or trailing spaces in your data.

To revert that update your existing table data like this

```
update table_name
set email = trim(email)
where email like '%some email%'
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you have blankspace in your email.
you can check the length of the email.

```
SELECT length(email) 
FROM  `table_name`
WHERE  `email` LIKE  '%email%'
```

use wildcard

```
select * from table_name 
where email like '%some email%'
```

or visit here for more combination `http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp`

Comment: lenght(email) returning length 2 more than the actual length of email stored in database for the emails which I not able to search using SELECT statement.

Comment: use trim function to trim the "some email" from your php code.like i said in your db the mysql is looking for "some email" but you have blank space inserted in your db for that name,which you mentioned that length function is returning 2more values, that means you have blank space ther alongwith the name. use $someemail= (trim($_POST['some email'])) when capturing from the form . it will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that when passing the variable in the code, it also left blank spaces between the double quotes and the variable, when removing this, it was not necessary to put the % character

This is my incorrect code, look at the blanks before and after the variable:

```
$resul = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `user` = ' ".$user." '");
```

This is the correct way:

```
$resul = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `user` = '".$user."'");
```

removing these spaces you won't need to use the wildcards%

I hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same error for just one email id in mysql `5.7.12`. Tried updating/trimming and whatnot, still no luck.

Changed the charset, which resolved the issue:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
CHANGE COLUMN email email VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```