# Unable to retrieve student info from MySQL database using PHP _POST on form input

Tags: php, mysql, database, post

I'm making a simple web app wherein in one of my database tables has two columns, ID and User.

In one file I have a form where I input a name. I then want receive input from the form using _POST and then query the database to retrieve that name's (student's) info and join with data from other tables.

The problem is I always get zero results from the database. However, if I modify the code to _POST the student's ID, then I get results from the database. So, I can't figure out why it doesn't work if I use the form to enter the name rather than ID.

Here is my form:

```
 echo '<form name="postStudent" action="studentListCourses.php" method="post">';

    echo 'Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="student">';

    echo '<input type="submit" value="save"/>';

echo '</form>';
```

And then on the studentListCourses file I use:

```
$student = $_POST['student'];
    // $student = (string)$student;
    echo $student; 
    echo '<br>';

    // Query DB for selected student
    $Tusers_SQLselect = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.User='".$student."';";
```

But I always get zero results from the database. If I change the last clause in the query to:

```
WHERE users.ID='".$student."';";
```

then I get the result back from my query, assuming I type in a valid ID in my form. Why can't I get result by typing in a valid name in the form?

Comment: Van you share the taboe structuren?

Comment: Come on 2+2.... What are you entering in the web page? A number like `2` or a name like `fred` Whatever you are entering it equated to being the `ID` and not the `User` column

Answer (score 1):

Despite searching answers for at least an hour before I posted my newbie question, I was not able to find an answer that helped me. However, I reverted to searching again and I found the answer here on this post:

[mysql select not woking for varchar field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115050/mysql-select-not-woking-for-varchar-field)

Apparently, I had leading or trailing spaces in my column data.

Thank you again for the side notes about SQL injection in previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$Tusers_SQLselect = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.User='$student'";
```

You don't need to concat the `$student`, just use quotes will do.

This will work provided your table column is `users.User`.

**Just a tip**: Please remember to prevent MySQL Injection.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you are querying the column that does not have the data that you expect. Verify that you have the correct data by manually selecting the records with `SELECT * FROM users`.

Also check that the data does not have any garbage characters. Try this:

```
select user,HEX(user) from users where user like '%Abdur%'
```

As a side note, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should escape user input that you read from the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Thank you for the side note. Also, I'm doing manual selection right now. If I select `WHERE users.ID='104'` then I get the result and the User in that row is Abdur. However if I do a manual select with `WHERE users.User='Abdur'` then I get zero result, despite the fact knowing the User column does indeed have an 'Abdur'.

Comment: Is this what you mean? `$student = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $student);`